# A puzzle-loving lady's phone number

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, visual, knowledge

> After a long day, you head to your local bar for a couple of drinks. Halfway through your second beer, a pretty girl walks up to you and points to the empty chair next to you. "Is this seat taken?" she asks sweetly.
>
> "No, not at all," you reply.
>
> She sits down, and after a brief chat, the two of you quickly bond over a mutual love of puzzles. Before long, you work up the courage to ask for her phone number. The girl takes out a piece of paper and a pen and starts writing something down, but when she passes the paper to you, instead of a phone number, there is the following:
>
> [image]
> "You seem like a smart guy," she says. "You should be able to work this out in five minutes." She gives you a flirty wink, then gets up and walks away, leaving you equal parts enamored and baffled. You're certain her number is of the standard American format, (xxx)-xxx-xxxx, but she doesn't seem to have given you much else to go on.
>
> Determined to figure it out, you down the rest of your beer, pull out a pen and paper of your own, and set to work trying to crack the puzzle...

What is the woman's phone number? **BONUS QUESTION:** Which state is she from?

Hint:

> Play close attention to the lady's parting remark: "You should be able to work this out in five minutes." There's an important hint in there somewhere.

Comment: By looking at R/B it seems R =Cipher Text and B=Plain Text according to red/black concept of cryptography. Not sure though.

Comment: Does this need the [tag:rebus] tag?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'll add a clue that should hopefully point people in the right direction.

Comment: Well, that first value certainly looks like a base '5' number.

Comment: @Doug.McFarlane Might as well tell you, it is indeed base 5. From there, you should probably post an answer to work out the following steps.

Comment: It was true love from the moment I spider.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Converting **1330132242112124** from base 5 to base 35 gives **SKYBLUE**(35) which interpreted as color name in RGB is (R=135,G=206,B=235). So multiplying R*2 and B*20 and writing it as phone number gives: **(270)-206-4700**. And if I'm right the state is **Kentucky**

Comment: Correct! It's just missing one tiny thing: where does the spider web fit into the equation?

Comment: @F1Krazy The only thing that pops in my mind is the web browser (wich is somehow related to a spider web) that can by used to interpret color name to actual RGB values.

Comment: Well, skyblue is a [web colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors). And I guess that the five minutes were meant as a hint that the number is in base 5?

Comment: @MOehm Yes and yes. I'll go ahead and mark this as accepted.